# Getting annotation value in a jersey request filter when @RequestFilters is used

Tags: annotations, jersey

The @RequestFilters annotation seems to remove any filters added with a RequestFilterFactory in the jersey config.
Is it possible to get the annotations in any other way?

Comment: Tried ExtendedUriInfo but abstractMethod is not set yet, when running the request filters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to solve this. I replaced @ResourceFilters with a @AnnotationAwareResourceFilters and then built a factory to create the different filters. I also added a new internal filter to the beginning of the filter list. This filter included a reference to the AbstractMethod allowing and put that into the request properties, allowing any filter to retrieve annotations later.